# Filter and scan a table DynamoDB in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

I have a table `Client` which contains information like this :

```
{
  "address": "XXX",
  "contact_email": "XXX",
  "id": 1,
  "password": "XXX",
}
```

The primary partition key is the `id` (Number) and I want to retrieve a client information by a `contact_email` using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

When you query the dynamodb, partition key is must. When you scan the dynamodb, partition key is optional. But Scan is slower than Query.

Try with this

```
var params = {
        "TableName": tableName,
        "FilterExpression": "contact_email = :val1",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":val1": contact_email
        },
        "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "TOTAL"
    };
```

Comment: I try something like this :  `$response = $client->scan([
        'TableName' => 'Client2',
        "FilterExpression": "contact_email = :val1",
        "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
            ":val1": "test@email.com"
        },
])`

but I have an error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ']' at this line "FilterExpression": "contact_email = :val1"